# Metadata not being displaying in Android-12 AAOS emulator

Tags: android, android-source, android-bluetooth, avrcp

I was able to connect the Android Automotive OS (AAOS) emulator to my Pixel 4a phone via Bluetooth using USB passthrough functionality in Android 12. However, when I played music from my phone, I could hear the sound in the emulator (on my host machine), but the metadata was not displayed.

As a trying purpose, I switched to Android version 12.1 and connected the AAOS emulator to my phone again. This time, in 12.1, the metadata started to appear in emulator, and I could hear the sound as well.

I have verified AVRCP profile version which is 1.5 default in both the Android(12 & 12.1) and also in my phone.

Bluetooth dongle which I am using is [TPLink](https://www.tp-link.com/sg/home-networking/adapter/ub400/)

Bluetooth passthrough [reference](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/start/passthrough#bluetooth)

Any help would be appreciated.